# Need for equality in the null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing

In statistical hypothesis testing, the alternate hypothesis is usually chosen to be the statement which bears the burden of proof. Also, the null hypothesis always has an equality ($\leq$ or $\geq$ for one sided tests and $=$ for two sided tests). For one sided tests, suppose the burden of proof lies on proving $\mu < a $. Then $H_0: \mu \geq a \ ; H_1: \mu < a $. Otherwise, if the burden of proof lies on proving $\mu > a $ then $H_0: \mu \leq a \ ; H_1: \mu > a $.

Now consider a two sided test: $H_0: \mu = a \ ; H_1: \mu \neq a $. Here the burden of proof lies in proving $\mu \neq a$.

My question is can we test the reverse: $H_0: \mu \neq a \ ; H_1: \mu = a $. We construct the pdf of the test statistic under the null hypothesis. If $H_0: \mu \neq a $, then since $\mu$ can take an infinite set of values, there would be an infinite set of pdf's. Hence the test is not feasible. For one sided tests, $\mu$
does take an infinite set of values under the null hypothesis. But supposing we are testing $H_0: \mu \leq a \ ; H_1: \mu > a $. Then, we can construct the pdf for $ \mu = a$. If the test statistic falls in the rejection region for the density function defined by $ \mu = a$ then it will also fall in the rejection region for all the pdf's constructed by taking values of $\mu < a$. Hence it suffices to consider a single pdf.

Is this line of reasoning correct that the hypothesis test $H_0: \mu \neq a \ ; H_1: \mu = a $ is not feasible?

Comment: Check [tag:tost]

Comment: Also [tag:equivalence]

Comment: one problem with the point alternative hypothesis is that you always know that it is false, since the point has 0 width, there is an 0 probability that the parameter is exactly that value. You can test an interval as @Tim suggested, or test whether h0 or h1 are more likely or more probable given the data

Comment: Thanks @Tim for pointing me to TOST.

Comment: Thanks @mkt for pointing me to equivalence testing.

Comment: Thanks @rep_ho for your comment. I did not think about the probability being zero. But what about the discrete case ? Lets say we keep selecting 13 cards from a deck of 52 cards each time shuffling the cards before drawing. I want to test whether the shuffling was adequate for randomizing the draw or not. If it was, then the proportion of hands in the population that contain a certain card say king of spades will be 13/52 = 1/4. If the shuffling was not adequate, then the proportion would be different from 1/4.

Comment: @rep_ho The problem you identify - that the point estimate of the null hypothesis is meaningless/illogical/impossible - is true in most normal applications of hypothesis testing as well.

Comment: @mkt-ReinstateMonica of course. what I wanted to say, that I can find a test statistic that is incompatible with h0 = 0, and infer that the parameter is likely not 0, however, I cannot find a test statistic incompatible with h0=[-inf, 0) + (0, inf] therefore I cannot use the same reasoning to say that the parameter most likely is not in h0